# sequelize index error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize to define my Model with postgres.
I have the following

```
@Options({
sequelize: db.main,
freezeTableName: true,
paranoid: true,
tableName: 'artist',
timestamps: true,
indexes: [{
    unique: true,
    fields: ['name'],
}],
})
@Attributes({
id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
},
name: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
},
```

My Q is how do I get a custom error message when I try to create an artist with the same name as in DB. As per http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#validations
I mean I can use

```
validate: {
    isIn: [['foo', 'bar']],
    msg: 'Validation error for Artists w.r.t length',
}
```

But I cant seem to get a custom error message for Index on Model.
It throws generic error message `lower(name) must be unique`
How do I add custom error message for sequelize Index

Answer (score 0):

"same name" means the unique index?

```
name: {
  type: DataTypes.TEXT,
  allowNull: false,
  unique: {
    msg: 'Validation error for Artists w.r.t length',
  }
}
```